# flask reqparse how to get empty list using action='append' (not by default)

Tags: python, flask-restful

i need to get empty list if it in request but also need to get None if argument don't given at all in request

if i defined argument like that

```
parser.add_argument('participating',type=int, nullable=False, action='append')
```

then if i do request like this

```
print(post('http://localhost:80/api/', json={'participating':[]}).json())
```

parser sees it like 'participating':None

and if i do that request

```
print(post('http://localhost:80/api/', json={}).json())
```

then parser also sees it like 'participating':None

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by check for exist key in flask.request.json

```
if not args['participating'] and 'participating' in flask.request.json and not flask.request.json['participating']:
    args['participating'] = flask.request.json['participating']
```

in that case values was:
args['participating'] = None
flask.request.json['participating'] = []
(but i open for any others solutions)